# How do I send values to the standard output stream and access those values in another program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    string strObservationStation = "";

    int intObs1 = 0;
    int intObs2 = 0;
    int intObs3 = 0;
    int intObs4 = 0;
    int intObs5 = 0;

    double dblW1 = 0;
    double dblW2 = 0;
    double dblW3 = 0;
    double dblW4= 0;
    double dblW5 = 0;

    cin >> strObservationStation;

    cin >> intObs1;
    cin >> intObs2;
    cin >> intObs3;
    cin >> intObs4;
    cin >> intObs5;

    cin >> dblW1;
    cin >> dblW2;
    cin >> dblW3;
    cin >> dblW4;
    cin >> dblW5;

    cout<<intObs1<<endl;
    cout<<intObs2<<endl;
    cout<<intObs3<<endl;
    cout<<intObs4<<endl;
    cout<<intObs5<<endl;


    cout<<dblW1<<endl;
    cout<<dblW2<<endl;
    cout<<dblW3<<endl;
    cout<<dblW4<<endl;
    cout<<dblW5<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

and then in my other program I want to access these values and do calculations ... Please help
This is a basic program
I also need to link this program to another by using a .bat file

Comment: How does the other program expect to access the data? Through stdin or command line args?

Comment: This other program can read from standard input, as you do already in your sample code. Then connect both programs through a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Form your post, I take it that you are working in Windows.

You can pipe the output of one program to another program in the Windows CMD shell.

```
program1.exe | my.bat
```

Of course, you can use absolute paths to any of those.